# OpenSSL SSL_read and SSL_write from multiple threads

Tags: multithreading, ssl, openssl

I know it is forbidden in the OpenSSL API to call `SSL_read` and `SSL_write` from two different threads on the same `SSL` context, but it's important in my application to have secure full-duplex communication.  I thought of some solutions, none of which I really like:

1. Use two `SSL` contexts per connection.  I don't like this because it uses more resources, and it would complicate my implementation.  However, I would be fine using this if I could just "duplicate" an existing `SSL` context rather than creating a whole new connection from scratch.
2. Use non-blocking sockets with a mutex controlling access to an `SSL` context.  This would require resource-hogging polling, and I heard the non-blocking implementation is just not very good.

This seems like it would be a rather common thing to do, so what is an accepted solution to this problem?

Comment: Short of putting a mutex around the read/write operations themselves instead? You might consider moving to a different SSL library. For instance, on Windows, its SChannel API lets you perform your own socket I/O, where you push read data into the SSL engine, and it gives you SSL data to send.  Then you would simply put a mutex around the engine access, and let your threads freely perform socket I/O as needed.

Comment: You could use [Boost.Asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html). With asynchronous I/O you can get full duplex on a single thread.

Comment: I'm not so sure boost will work with a single thread.  What if the thread is blocking on a read while you want to do a write?

Comment: @user1887231 Boost.Asio asynchronous calls do not block.

Answer (score 4):

> Use non-blocking sockets with a mutex controlling access to an SSL context.

With non-blocking sockets inside a single thread you would not need mutexes, because you only either read or write (because of single thread).

> This would require resource-hogging polling, ...

You would not need "resource-hogging" polling. I assume you mean here busy polling instead of using the usual facilities of the system (like `select`) to wait (not loop) until data are available or data can be send. But contrary to read/write on plain sockets, SSL sockets can need a read if they want to write and a write if they want to read and they might have data inside even if the socket is not readable. Look out for `SSL_WANT_READ`, `SSL_WANT_WRITE` and `SSL_pending`.

> ...and I heard the non-blocking implementation is just not very good.

It looks more complex if you are used to using threads. But did you ever wonder why high performance servers like nginx don't use threads but non-blocking I/O? That is because it needs less resources and has not the problems associated with threads, like needing to mutex your way around critical sections (overhead) and getting strange and sporadic errors when forgetting to mutex something. nginx also uses openssl with non-blocking I/O.

I personally use non-blocking I/O all the time and while it is harder to do correctly with SSL because of the protocol itself and not the OpenSSL implementation it is doable and fast.

This means, that non-blocking I/O within a single thread is a way you could go to solve your problem. The other way would be to let SSL only work with memory BIOs instead of real file descriptors and do all the reading and writing yourself. But this is probably even more complex than non-blocking I/O.

BTW, usually *SSL context* means the `SSL_CTX` object which can be shared between multiple SSL connections and which has probably no problems with multiple threads. What you mean is that the same *SSL connection* (the `SSL` object) should not be used from multiple threads.